# Location of cd executable

Tags: linux, exec

I read that the executables for the commands issued using exec() calls are supposed to be stored in directories that are part of the PATH variable.

Accordingly, I found the executables for `ls, chmod, grep, cat` in /bin.

However, I could not find the executable for `cd`.

Where is it located?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A process can only affect its own working directory. When an executable is executed by the shell it executes as a child process, so a cd executable (if one existed) would change that child process's working directory without affecting the parent process (the shell), hence the cd command must be implemented as a shell built-in that actually executes in the shell's own process.

Comment: can you tell me any other alternative binary for "cd"??

Comment: @zappy Quoting my answer: "the cd command must be implemented as a shell built-in". In other words, you cannot have a `cd` binary.

Answer (score 7):

cd is a shell built-in, unfortunately.

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

...from http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/whereis-cd-sudo-doesnt-find-cd-464767/

But you should be able to get it working with:

```
sh -c "cd /somedir; do something"
```

Comment: the type command was really useful in understanding this concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Not all utilities that you can execute at a shell prompt need actually exist as actual executables in the filesystem. They can also be so-called *shell built-ins*, which means – you guessed it – that they are built into the shell.

The Single Unix Specification does, in general, *not* specify whether a utility has to be provided as an executable or as a built-in, that is left as a private internal implementation detail to the OS vendor.

The only exceptions are the so-called [*special built-ins*](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), which *must* be provided as built-ins, because they affect the behavior of the shell *itself* in a manner that regular executables (or even regular built-ins) can't (for example `set`, which sets variables that persist even after `set` exits). Those special built-ins are:

- `break`
- `:`
- `continue`
- `.`
- `eval`
- `exec`
- `exit`
- `export`
- `readonly`
- `return`
- `set`
- `shift`
- `times`
- `trap`
- `unset`

Note that `cd` is *not* on that list, which means that `cd` is not a special built-in. In fact, [according to the specification](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html), it would be perfectly legal to implement `cd` as a regular executable. It's just not possible, for the reasons given by the other answers.

And if you scroll down to the non-normative section of the specification, i.e. to the part that is not officially part of the specification but only purely informational, you will find that fact explicitly mentioned:

> Since cd affects the current shell execution environment, it is always provided as a *shell regular built-in*.

So, the specification doesn't require `cd` to be a built-in, but it's simply impossible to do otherwise.

Note that sometimes utilities are provided both as a built-in *and* as an executable. A good example is the `time` utility, which on a typical GNU system is provided both as an executable by the Coreutils package and as a shell regular built-in by Bash. This can lead to confusion, because when you do `man time`, you get the manpage of the `time` executable (the `time` builtin is documented in `man builtins`), but when you execute `time` you get the `time` built-in, which does not support the same features as the `time` executable whose manpage you just read. You have to explicitly run `/usr/bin/time` (or whatever path you installed Coreutils into) to get the executable.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/posix/cd), `cd` is always a built-in command and *never* an executable:

> Since cd affects the current shell execution environment, it is always provided as a shell regular built-in.

Answer (score 2):

`cd` is part of the shell; an internal command. There is no binary for it.

Answer (score 2):

The command cd is built-in in your command line shell. It could not affect the working directory of your shell otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched the executable of "cd" and there is no such.
You can work with chdir (pathname) in C, it has the same effect.