# Having an alias with multiple commands, is it possible to pass an argument to the first command?

Tags: python, bash, alias, slurm

I am beginner in programming/scripting and stuck with the following problem. I searched a lot on stack overflow and the net but could not resolve the issue. The detailed situation I face is described below in case somebody has a completely different approach to solve the problem.

Is there a way to use an `alias` (that I call `go_to`) with multiple commands but where I can pass an `argument` to only the first `command1`?

I want to execute `goto argument` from something like `alias go_to='command1 ; command2'`.

`command1` should evaluate a `path` based on the `argument` and `command2` should `cd` to there.

### Situation in detail

I'm executing calculations on a computer facility that uses the slurm batch system to queue and start jobs. Using the command `squeue` slurm shows all running and pending jobs including their Job_ID. Using `sjobs <Job_ID>` a bunch of information are displayed, including the path where the calculation was started. My goal is to go to that directory.
Of course I can do that:

1. `squeue` to see all jobs and their Job_ID,
2. Pick one of the Job_IDs,
3. `sjobs <Job_ID>` to display information,
4. Search with my eyes for the line that includes the path, copy the path and
5. `cd path` to arrive where I want to go.

That is a lengthy procedure if you want to check multiple calculations. Therefore, I want to use a alias and/or a bash or python script (let's call it `go_to`) so that I simply need to type `go_to <Job_ID>` to arrive at the directory.

So far, using a python script I achieved to do `python script.py <Job_ID>` to call `sjobs` and extract the `path` from it (but piping sjobs to grep and sed would also be possible).
I've already read
[Why doesn't "cd" work in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script) and [Location of cd executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741148/location-of-cd-executable) and understood that `os.chdir(path)` or `subprocess.call(['cd',path])` will only change directories inside the python subshell and that as soon as the script is finished I will end up in the same directory where I started the script.

From what I understand only an `alias` can bring me to `path`. Therefore, my idea was to output the `path` from the python script into a file, e.g. `Path.txt` to be usable by an alias. Using the alias

`alias go_to='cd $(head -1 /absolute/path/to/Path.txt)'` 
it is possible to change to the desired `path`. But that involves letting the python script run beforehand. 
The actual problem for me now is to do that in one step as I need to pass the `<Job_ID>` to evaluation of the `path` first.

As I said, I am quite new to scripting, so any alternative ways are welcome.

Comment: You can't pass arguments to *any* alias; use a function instead.

Comment: I see, but that does not solve the problem I am facing. A function is placed inside a script. And the script will only change the directory while it is running and after it is completed return to the directory where it started. So even a function will not help. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You are half wrong/half right. A function is placed inside a script, right. The script will only change the directory while it is running, false. Try to put that function in your ~/.bashrc file and you will discover that, while the function is in a script, it will be available despite the ~/.bashrc file is processed when starting the shell.

Comment: Whatever you do to define your alias in the current shell will work to define a function in the current shell as well.

Comment: @chepner, I reckon you should  take your two comments and make an answer out of them. (that should be accepted and upvoted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function to call the two commands instead. The argument to the function can be passed to the first command.

```
go_to () {
    command1 "$1"
    command2
}
```

Comment: Knowing now the trick, this was also particularly helpful for me as a scripting beginner: https://superuser.com/questions/106272/how-to-call-bash-functions