# How to run commands after login to shell command of a container in a VM?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, containers, kubernetes-pod

when I ran this command

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | grep container-name | awk '{print $1}') /bin/sh
```

I ssh into my container,

```
/src #
```

Now - I want to add 2 more commands so I did

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | grep container-name | awk '{print $1}') /bin/sh ; cd app/Http/Controllers; ls -lrt;
```

but I still see this

```
/src #
```

I am supposed to see this

```
/src # cd app/Http/Controllers; ls -lrt;                                                
total 44                                                                                
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           361 Jun 11 11:27 Controller.php                   
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1734 Jun 11 11:27 ClientController.php             
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1702 Jun 11 11:27 BroadcastController.php        
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          5257 Jun 17 15:24 NodeController.php              
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2844 Jun 17 20:21 AccountController.php          
/src/app/Http/Controllers #
```

Comment: can you try : `kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | grep container-name | awk '{print $1}') -- bash -c "cd app/Http/Controllers && ls -lrt" `  or `kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | grep container-name | awk '{print $1}') -- sh -c "cd app/Http/Controllers && ls -lrt"`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan : it doesn't seem to work... see this  https://i.imgur.com/ZVe47O4.png

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to go inside docker container do as below

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | grep container-name | awk '{print $1}') -- ls -lrt /app/Http/Controllers;
```

kubectl will execute every command inside container which comes after `--`. also you can mount your target directory and perform `ls` on localhost. create a yaml file like the one here.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-container
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: my-container
    volumeMounts:
    - name: my-storage
      mountPath: /data/
  volumes:
  - name: my-storage
    hostPath:
        # directory location on host
        path: /opt/data
        # this field is optional
        type: Directory
```

then run this command `kubectl apply -f your-file.yaml`

Comment: it doesn't seem to work... see this  https://i.imgur.com/ZVe47O4.png

Comment: edited my answer , run it see if it is working or not. the problem is after -- bash or sh will execute the commands and cd is not part of them. check following link for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741148/location-of-cd-executable

Comment: How comes u don't need /bin/sh ??

Comment: You latest answer return similar error:   https://i.imgur.com/suN0pOJ.png

Comment: that's not bug, simply tells you there is no /app/http directory or Controllers file.

Comment: do this, kubectl exec -it <container-name> bash/sh. after that do ls manually to see if the directory exists.

Comment: yes directory exist. See this : https://i.imgur.com/cwTE8g9.png - I think you have an extra trailing `/` in front of the `/app/` , it should be `app/`

Comment: I tried that, it seems to work, but it - auto existing out of my prompt... I want it to stay.

Comment: Do u know why ? It exiting the prompt.

Comment: guess there is no way to do what you want in on line. why do you want to stay attach after ls command? wouldn't it better if you mount tmp directory and access it from host?